# How to convert UTM to degrees coordinates

Tags: python, geolocation, coordinates, energy

I'm pretty new to python and I need help on turning this coordinates from UTM to decimals.

If someone could help I will be forever in debt..
Regards

| East | North | Zone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300471 | 6282670 | 19H |
| 267390 | 6353815 | 19H |
| 712859 | 5826350 | 18H |

I've been trying to use the pyproj library but I don't know if I'm using the correct sintax or if there is another code for the UTM that I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Which degrees coordinates? I do not want to spoiler you, but UTM is old, and so it used different geographic coordinates comparing what we are using now (and I never saw an official document which tell us if we should interpret sectors on original globe, or just on "GPS" (WGS84) coordinate system. And every country has (or had) different geographic coordinate system. So careful (and always document) with the coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

The utm package features an in-built function directly applying to your problem. For instance, for the first parameter set you can apply

```
import utm
utm.to_latlon(300471, 6282670, 19, 'H')
```

which yields the output

```
>>> (-33.577026625458686, -71.1498294516708)
```